# Block IP in DNS Zone File (Instead of Domain)

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone, rpz

I'm using bind9 DNS server. I used to block websites using their domain name in RPZ zone file such as:

`malicious.example   CNAME   .`

But, I need to block IP rather than domain such as:
`192.0.2.4   CNAME   .`

How can I do this? Or, is the above example (`192.0.2.4   CNAME   .`) correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

IP addresses are used directly in packets. They are not translated into anything. To block IP's you have to use a firewall.

In case you want to block *results* containing a set of IP's, [Patrick's answer covers that](https://serverfault.com/a/1126081/435764).

Comment: What does "packages" mean in that sentence? What packages? You mean network packets?

Comment: Also, you are wrong, bind documentation clearly state it is possible (to filter by IP address)

Comment: "To block IP's you have to use a firewall." When you use a "DNS firewall" which is what the RPZ  feature is, the goal is not to block network traffic at the IP level but to change how resolution happens, to change results in some way to implement local policies.

Comment: He asks how to block IP's. IP's are never queried to the nameserver. They're used in the packet header.

Comment: I don't think you understand what bind RPZ feature is nor how it works. If you say, per my answer, that you want to "block" a given IP it means the resolver will never give back that IP address to client, and as such the client can not connect to it, because it won't know about it in the first place.

Comment: I understand that part. I just don't believe that's what OP is asking ;)

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.isc.org/docs/BIND_RPZ.pdf, page 11:

> Creating a trigger rule for an IP or Subnet (v4)
>
> Let’s say we want to rewrite any DNS queries for any hosts that resolve in the 172.16.3.0/24 subnet.
>
> `24.0.3.16.172.ns-ip IN CNAME .`
>
> As you can see, the octets in the subnet need to be reversed (similar to the way rbl in-addr.arpa works). The first number
> represents the subnet mask. If we only wanted to block a single ip, the first number would be 32, which represents a /32, i.e.:
> `32.1.3.16.172.ns-ip IN CNAME`

See also https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-dnsop-dns-rpz-00#section-4.3 which shows a use of `rpz-ip` instead of `ns-ip` (RPZ feature was first invented by/in bind, and there are attempts to make it a full standard)

Hence, it will also depend on which bind version you are using, which you don't disclose. Look at its included documentation, and the level of RPZ support it has.